# Is NancyFx reverse routing like ASP.NET MVC supported?

Tags: c#, nancy

ASP.NET MVC allow very usable way of generating stongly typed URL like:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action<AccountSettingsController>(c => c.BusinessInfo()))">Business info</a>
```

or even:

```
<a href="@(Url.Action<SomeOtherController>(c => c.SomeActionMethod(id, paramX, paramY)))">Business info</a>
```

Using simple custom URL helper:

```
public static string Action<TController>(
    this UrlHelper urlHelper,
    Expression<Action<TController>> action,
    string fragment = null
) where TController : BaseController
{
    var routeValues = InternalExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);
    var url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
            routeName: null,
            actionName: null,
            controllerName: null,
            protocol: null,
            hostName: null,
            fragment: fragment,
            routeValues: routeValues,
            routeCollection: urlHelper.RouteCollection,
            requestContext: urlHelper.RequestContext,
            includeImplicitMvcValues: true
        );
    return url;
}
```

It allows changing URL mapping in one place (RouteConfig) and any Controllers and Actions re-factoring doesn't mean you need to go and update each link.

I like NancyFx for it's simplicity and good IoC out of the box, but what i'm not sure why NanxyFx doesn't have support of reverse-routing (generating URL based on the action name) so it would be possible to create some static-typing helper for it.

Any ideas how to implement it in NancyFx or why if it's not possible to do, then why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are not named in Nancy so there's currently no way to implement such a feature.

But if you ever find yourself changing routes then I think you have a much bigger issue to begin with, personally this awesome feature (or lack of in your current case) has made me think more about what I'm making my routes, and so I now rarely, if ever, need to change my routes.

If I do need to rename a route, Find All makes it pretty quick to fix.

Comment: I took absolutely the same approach for my own project. For office job we use ASP.NET MVC and request like put this item to other menu, rename it, synchronize URL with menu name comes very often and named routes helped in this case a lot.

Comment: Ahh, that makes it harder, I would just give them the ability to change the name but keep the url the same. Especially if its a public facing site.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer used to be right, but now there's [Linker](https://github.com/horsdal/Nancy.Linker).

It doesn't do the expression parsing out of the box but it basically pulls parameters from property name-value pairs (like a `RouteValueDictionary`) so adding support for extracting the parameters from an expression tree shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: There are examples of linker usage to build URLs that takes no parameters ` var absoluteLink = linker.BuildAbsoluteUri(this.Context, "aNamedRoute", parameters: new {id = 123})` it means that the parameter is set in the module. But what if I need a "template url" for a blog posts and pass the ID of each post in the view? To have something like absoluteLink(someBlogPostIntParam)

Comment: @Zelid - I think I'm misunderstandng your question because it seems like you're answering the question in the question.  `linker.BuildAbsoluteUri(this.Context, "aNamedTemplateRouteWithSomeBlogPostIntParam", new { someBlogPostIntParam = 123, postTitleSlug = this.Context.Items["linked-post-title"].ToLower().Replace(' ', '-') })` to get a route that's named `aNamedTemplateRouteWithSomeBlogPostIntParam` and has a template path like `posts/{someBlogPostIntParam:int}/{postTitleSlug}`.  Now, I think what you might be getting at is the route isn't named and for some reason you can't change that, so...

Comment: @Zelid ...  You could access it just by the templated path itself.  If you check out the source for [Nancy.Linker](https://github.com/horsdal/Nancy.Linker/blob/master/src/Nancy.Linker/ResourceLinker.cs) you'll see a private `List<RouteDescription> AllRoutes` property and how it's retrieved (not too complicated).  By default, Linker has support for retrieving named routes by default but you could easily implement the same for retrieving them by path. Both are accessed from the [`RouteDescription`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Routing/RouteDescription.cs) class. get it?

Comment: The question is that for the route named `aNamedTemplateRouteWithSomeBlogPostIntParam` you already predefined parameter `someBlogPostIntParam = 123`. Let's say I want to list links of all posts in one page, how can I do that? From what I understood, calling the `aNamedTemplateRouteWithSomeBlogPostIntParam` will generate link to the blog post with ID 123 only. In ASP.NET MVC I would do foreach in razor template and iterate over all posts getting the title and the id of post and passing them to the linkbuilder tag. With Linker seems that I don't have access to pass parameters in the view.

Comment: @Zelid `someBlogPostIntParam = 123` is a parameter assignment, not a definition.  The definition would be `posts/{someBlogPostIntParam:int}/{postTitleSlug}` and the only constraint on that parameter is that it must be convertible to an integer